# UpdateModel has no effect in my action controller after posting new values

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

Below is a portion of my controller:

```
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult Edit(string IdAffaire)
    {
        Affaire affaire = this.repository.Retrieve(IdAffaire);

        if (affaire == null)
        {
            return Redirect("~/");
        }

        var model = new AffaireEditViewModel
        {
            Affaire = affaire,
            Status = repository.RetrieveStatus().Select(o => new SelectListItem { Text = o.Name, Value = o.IdStatus.ToString() }).ToList(),
        };

        return View(model);
    }

    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult Edit(string idAffaire, AffaireEditViewModel model)
    {
        Affaire affaire = repository.Retrieve(idAffaire);

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return this.Edit(model.Affaire.IdAffaire);
        }

        try
        {
            UpdateModel(affaire);

            repository.Save();

            return RedirectToAction("Detail", "Affaire", new { idAffaire = idAffaire });
        }
        catch
        {
            return View(affaire);
        }

    }
```

Below is my ViewModel for edit:

```
public class AffaireEditViewModel
{
    public Affaire Affaire { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Status { get; set; }
}
```

Below is my Affaire model:

```
public class Affaire
{
    [Key]
    public string IdAffaire { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public Int16? IdStatus { get; set; }
    public Int16? IdLabel { get; set; }
    // ....
}
```

**My problem** is that when posting new values in my edit view page, the action named Edit is well triggered (posting) with right values, but the statement **UpdateModel(affaire)**  has no effect! Any help is greatly appreciated.

**EDITED**

I found the problem.

I need to change from this:

```
UpdateModel(affaire);
```

To this:

```
UpdateModel(affaire,"Affaire");
```

I guess it is because my view model is composed of several things and I need to tell explicitly to my UpdateModel function which element to use. Can somebody confirm?

Answer (score 0):

To verify - is your repository retaining a reference to that instance of the model? I see you call save - but I don't see the implementation of the save since you aren't passing in a model to it.

Comment: as you can see I edited my question because I found the solution.